# Find out hit child with RaycastHit

Tags: c#, unityscript, unity, raycasting

Let's assume having a (2d-) gameobject with 3 images: Head, body, feet.
By using `RaycastHit2D` I can find out if the gameobject was hit (for example by the mouse):

```
RaycastHit2D newSelectedObject = Physics2D.Raycast(cameraVector, Vector2.zero);
```

Now I'd like to find out if the head, body or feet was hit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

2D objects can not be checked for collision with mouse using that code. This code is working only when you cast a ray on a 2D plane and it comes from side of an object.

But when you want to check 2D object being hit by mouse you need this:

```cs
Ray pressRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(pressRay, Mathf.Infinity);
GameObject hitGameObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
```

Anyway, when you check for collision you need to traverse [RaycastHit2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit2D.html) structure to find GameObject that is affected by hit either using `hit.transform.gameObject` notation or `hit.collider.gameObject`.

I advise to attach colliders to each child, set `IsTrigger = true` and use second notation.